# How to find out the cost of deploying a contract in HardHat

Tags: solidity, gas, hardhat

I deploy the contract to the Rinkeby. Can I calculate the contract deployment cost from HardHat?

Comment: Use the hardhat gas report plugin then write and run a unit test , it will show u how much gas the deployment consumed.

Answer (score 5):

If you `npm install hardhat-gas-reporter` in your project directory so that it appears in your package.json then whenever you execute a unit test file from your test folder it should log you a chart like this:
[image: Avg. Deployments is where you find the gas cost for deployment]

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to a standalone hardhat fork of mainnet and monitor the logs. It will give you something like this:

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Contract deployment: <UnrecognizedContract>
  Contract address:    0x6345e5...
  Transaction:         0xee7f0f...
  From:                0xf39fd6...
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            3439611 of 3439611
  Block #18153240:     0x9963cd...
```